# Why does Jarda attack Jason in The Bourne Supremacy after telling him where his car keys are and even suggesting how to escape?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-supremacy

In the movie The Bourne Supremacy, why does Jarda attack Jason when they are in his house **after** he agrees to escape with him and tells him his car keys are in his pocket and that they should go out the back? I thought after their initial confrontation, they were on ‘good’ grounds.

After Jason breaks into Jarda’s home, he makes Jarda tie his hands together with the cable ties, Jason asks him a few questions. When he is not satisfied with the answers, he kicks Jarda’s chair over, and Jarda falls to the ground (in a vulnerable position). Then later, Jarda says “I thought you came to kill me” and when it was clear (or I thought it was) that Jason just wanted answers and *not* there to kill him, there was a moment of stillness (no one did anything to hurt the other). I think they were on ‘good’ grounds because when Jarda got up from the ground, before he said “I thought you came to kill me”, Jason didn’t do anything to incapacitate him again, like knock him back to the ground or make him turn around. They could have escaped together and Jason could have had many of his questions answered if he kept Jarda alive.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does Jarda attack Jason
>
> They could have escaped together and Jason could have had many of his questions answered if he kept Jarda alive.

## Jarda was trying to capture/kill Bourne

It's pretty clear that Jarda had called for assistance (apparently by using his home security keypad) and **was playing for time** (he even looks at his watch) then....when the phone rings...

Jarda attacks Bourne

There's no doubt about that. Bourne then defends himself **in a fight to the death**, and don't forget that every moment is vital since help for Jarda is incoming.

Comment: Right.. for all we know, one of the only reasons Jarda is still alive after Treadstone is because he's a trap for Bourne (though, they never mention this in film). But either way, for these trained assassins, aside form Bourne (who's seeking answers), they have a tendency of -- kill now, ask questions later.

Comment: I know he called for assistance. But he called _before_ he found out Jason wasn't there to kill him. That's why I thought he sounded/acted at least a teeny bit remorseful when Jason asked "Did you call them in?", and being remorseful for his error, Jarda tells Jason where his car keys and car is. That's how I always interpreted it.

Comment: Jarda is **faking** remorseful....he'll tell  Bourne anything at this point even, apparently, co-operating just to play for time.

Comment: I was going to ask this same question. The problem, from my point of view, with the idea that Jarda was just trying to buy some time is that he actually directed Bourne to the fact that he called for backup. Bourne didn't even seem to suspect that he called it in until Jarda said "I thought you were here to kill me." It seems like he could've kept quiet about that and waited for them to either arrive or for the phone to ring. And by the time Jarda said "I thought you were here to kill me," Bourne seemed to have made it clear that he wasn't there to kill Jarda.

So, I still don't understand.